Getting wrong source ip address for time-to-live exceeded icmp packets on Android
below is the native ICMP utility code I use in my Android app for 'ping' purposes.
I decided adding trace route functionality and tried to use the same code with ttl=1, ttl=2 and so on.
However, on my real device the response ip address from this code for ttl=1, ttl=2, ttl=3 is always 123.0.0.0.
To verify if this is right or not - I took another'ping' app from Play Market, put ttl=1, ttl=2, ttl=3 and for each of these it shows legitimate reply ip address, like 192.168.0.1, 100.101.101.2, etc.
Do you know the reason ? what's wrong with this code ?
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "cppcoreguidelines-avoid-magic-numbers"

#include "icmp_util.h"

#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <map>

std::map<int, sockaddr_in> addr_map;

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "hicpp-signed-bitwise"
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "readability-magic-numbers"

u_short checksum(u_short *buf, int len) {

    u_long sum = 0;

    while (len > 1) {
        sum += *buf++;
        len -= sizeof(u_short);
    }

    if (len)
        sum += *(u_char *) buf;

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (u_short) (~sum);
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

int create_icmp_socket(const char *host, int timeout_ms, int ttl) {

    struct timeval t_out;
    t_out.tv_sec = MS_TO_SEC(timeout_ms);
    t_out.tv_usec = MS_TO_USEC(timeout_ms);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP); // NOLINT(android-cloexec-socket)

    if (sock < 0) {
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl)) != 0) {
        close(sock);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *) &t_out, sizeof(t_out)) != 0) {
        close(sock);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &(addr.sin_addr)) < 0) {
        close(sock);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    addr_map[sock] = addr;
    return sock;
}

void close_icmp_socket(int sock) {
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(sock);
    addr_map.erase(sock);
}

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "misc-non-private-member-variables-in-classes"

int ping(int sock, u_short sequence, const int size, jbyte *pattern, jsize pattern_len, char *ip_address) {
    char packet_data[size + sizeof(icmphdr)];
    struct icmphdr *hdr = (struct icmphdr *) &packet_data;
    struct timespec time_start, time_end;
    struct sockaddr_in addr = addr_map[sock], r_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len;

    bzero(packet_data, sizeof(packet_data));

    hdr->type = ICMP_ECHO;
    hdr->un.echo.id = htons(getpid());
    hdr->un.echo.sequence = htons(sequence);
    if (pattern_len > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + pattern_len) {
            int chunk_size = size - i;
            if (chunk_size > pattern_len)
                chunk_size = pattern_len;
            memcpy(packet_data + i + sizeof(icmphdr), pattern, (size_t) chunk_size);
        }
    }
    hdr->checksum = checksum((u_short *) &packet_data, sizeof(packet_data));

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_start);
    if (sendto(sock, packet_data, sizeof(packet_data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        return SEND_ERROR;
    }

    addr_len = sizeof(r_addr);
    int resp = recvfrom(sock, packet_data, sizeof(packet_data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &r_addr, &addr_len);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_end);

    // Extract IP address from r_addr
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(r_addr.sin_addr), ip_address, INET_ADDRSTRLEN); // here ip_address will contain 123.0.0.0

    if (resp <= 0) {
        return SEND_TIMEOUT;
    }

    double elapsed = ((double) (time_end.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec)) / 1000000.0;
    return (int) ((time_end.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + elapsed);
}

